# Failing to download or move file to external storage

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-tv

Using internal storage all works fine.
But when trying to download to external storage I'm getting "PLATFORM ERROR" or "Incorrect destination" errors.
Using the path: 
{storage.label}/dir

I'm able to create empty directories and text files on external storage using the File system API.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using `storage.label` as path.
You need to `resolve` the `storage.label` and use the `directory.fullPath`.